# why it did't display fetch response with Botton onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, axios

What's wrong in my Button.js and index.js? After I pass the user props to the panel component, user={contact.name} in index.js, it shows:

" Invariant Violation Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h2 (created by Panel)
    in div (created by Panel)
    in div (created by Panel)
    in Panel (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App "

how can I generate a random user information when pressing the button, and display the data information above the button?

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Panel from "./ProfilePanel";
import axios from 'axios';
import './index.css';
import Button from './Button';

const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contacts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchdata();
  }

  fetchdata() {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ contacts: res.data.results});
      });
  }

  render(){
    const {contacts} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="panel">
          {contacts.map(contact => (
          <div class="panel">
            <Panel
              key={contact.picture} avatar={contact.picture.medium} user={contact.name}
            />
            <li class="flex-container">
              <Button title="name" >
                <p key={contact.name} user={contact.name}></p>
              </Button>
              <Button title="location" onClick={this.fetchdata}> 
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.email} title="email">
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.phone} title="phone">
              </Button>
              <Button key={contact.login.password} title="password">
              </Button>
            </li>
          </div>
            ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

ProfilePanel.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import './index.css';
import Button from './Button';

const style={
  borderRadius: 150,
  margin: 15,
}

class Panel extends Component {

  render() {
    const { avatar,  user } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="Panel">
        <div class="panels">
          <div className="avatar">
            <img src={avatar} class="imageStyle" alt="" width={"200%"} height={"auto"}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <h2 className="user">{user}</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Panel;
```

Button.js

```
import './index.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Button extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open:false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    const {open} = this.state;
    return (
      <button className={` ${open ? 'open' : ''}`} 
      class='button' onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
        <div className="panel-heading">
          <h2 class='buttoncenter'>{title}</h2>
        </div>
      </button>
    );
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      open: ture
    })
  }
  }

  export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error it says

`(found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in h2 (created by Panel)`

This means you are trying to render out an object in your JSX which is not allowed. It is inside your heading in your Panel component. You will need to render out the name or destructure it further `{user.first}`

```
<h2 className="user">{user}</h2>
```

On an additional side not, might just be in this post but in your button component in your handle click you might have a typo. Should it be `open: true` ?

```
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      open: ture
    })
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it still not display the information that I fetch after I change to <h2 className="user">{user}</h2> and open : true

Comment: No ignore the `open: true`, it is the `{user}` object that is causing you the error. Change that to`{user.first}`

Comment: `<h2 className="user">{user.first}</h2>`

Comment: Okay, thanks. The name is display in the screen now. However, this is not what I ask for, I am asking how to use a button to display the API data? which is when I am pressing different button, it will display the different data information according to the which button I press such as I want to know the location information when I pressing the location botton. Can you help me out? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check `contact.name`
This seems to be an object, and in Panel you are trying to print out the object inside an h2 tag

```
<h2 className="user">{user}</h2>
```